# How to monitor/remove dowloaded movies and music from network storage?

Tags: monitoring, storage

I am looking for some solution to remove or list all movies that are dowloaded on our network storage. We are running short on free space and I noticed that a lot of people started downloading movies and music and then store it on network drive. Is there any better solution than writing a script that will run in cron and send me by mail all files larger than 500MB, for example?

Comment: If you want to be mean: look for files with extensions *.mp4, *.mov, *.avi, *.mpg, *.mp3, *.wav, etc. and delete them automatically. `find /mnt/storage -regex ".*\.\(mp4\|mov\|avi\|mpg\|mp3\|wav\)" -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Leave a notice in the shared directories saying that video and audio files will be automatically removed every week, then run simlev's command every monday. :>

Comment: Only problem is that there are work realeted videos that has to stay...

Comment: I would have thought that a good approach would be a people-management one, where you ask/tell people not to download music or videos. (Or not to save them to the NAS, depending on your country's legal position on this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solutions are to either:

1. Upgrade your storage so you have more space.

or:

2. Talk to people and get them to quit putting things on the disk and not deleting them.

or, if 1 is not an option and 2 fails:

3. Set up usage quotas for everyone, and enforce them.  THis will require everyone  to authenticate as themselves however, but they should become more space conscious because *they* will run out of space before the NAS system does.

Barring those two options, there are all kinds of tricks you can pull with `find` to get to only list stuff you actually care about.  In particular, you can match on particular file owners (or all owners except a set you list), file size, and last modification time (technically you can match on access time too, but you should avoid that as access time is unreliable).

Expanding on the command in the comments, you might try:

```
find /mnt/storage -regex ".*\.\(mp4\|mov\|avi\|mpg\|mp3\|wav\)" -type f -mtime +28 -exec rm {} \;
```

That will additionally only touch things that are actually files (the `-type f` clause excludes directories, symlinks, sockets, etc.) that are more than 28 days old (the `-mtime 28` clause does this).  In place of the `-exec` clause, you could just have it print the results and handle things yourself (though of course you can fine tune it to ignore 'work' files instead, and then just not have to deal with it until you update what constitutes a 'work' file).

Comment: Well I did this
`find /mnt/storage -regex ".*\.\(mp4\|mov\|avi\|mpg\|mp3\|wav\)" -type f -mtime +28 > videos_music.txt`

Then in vim this to remove all hidden directories
`:g/\.\//d`

and finally this to get total size of all files that are music and videos
`for I in` `cat videos_music.txt` `; do du -ch | grep total ; done`

Then it was just 2 hours worth of work to got throw the list and remove all the work unrealeted things.